# Keyboard does not move ScrollView up when window has FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS

Tags: android, keyboard, scrollview, statusbar

I've made sample layout - just a scrollview with many ETs and I've run into a problem where when I try to write text to f.e last EditText it is hidden behind displayed keyboard.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

works, but I need to be able to scroll whole layout even with keyboard up.

That just happens when I'm playing with status bar, otherwise it works completly ok:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
```

I get it that it gives window flag SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE, but is there any way to make keyboard move scrollview up just like when there is standard appbar? Can't find explanation for this behaviour.

This is my xml:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:title="Hello"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:background="#303F9F">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:hint="test"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:hint="test1"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:hint="test2"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:hint="test3"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:hint="test4"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:hint="test5"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:hint="test6"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:hint="test7"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:hint="test8"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:hint="test9"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:hint="test10"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:hint="test11"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks for any help or advice!

Comment: try removing `android:fillViewport="true"` from `ScrollView`

Comment: Nope, did no difference